# Python Google Search Webscraping Query Error: builtins.TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tld'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I've been dabbling around with Webscraping using Python and Google Search queries. When I try and perform the query using random text from a text file Ive generated I receive the following error:
**line 234, in 
for j in search(query, tld="ca", num=10, stop=10, pause = pause_rand, user_agent= str(headers)):**

**Error: builtins.TypeError: search() got an unexpected keyword argument 'tld'**
I use this python code in two separate machines, one of the machines does not receive this error and runs without any issue while the second machine has the error occur. As far as I am aware the two different machines should be running the same version of python etc

```
with open(""+elems+"", "r", encoding='utf8') as a_file:
        mydoc = Document()
        #print(filename)
        mydoc.add_paragraph("Results for " +str(filename_for_analysis[counter])+ ":")        
        line_num = 1
        for line in a_file:
            if line.strip():
                stripped_line = line.strip()
                mydoc.add_paragraph("Results for Line#"+str(line_num)+'\n'+str(stripped_line)+"")
                #results_file = open("Results.txt", "a+", encoding = 'utf-8')
                stack = []
                confirmedSite_stack = []
                safeSite_stack = []
                ErrorSite_stack = []
                Downloadable_stack = []
                FoundText = []
                print("Line:")
                print(stripped_line)
                query = scramble(stripped_line)
                print("Query:")
                print(query)
                pause_rand = random.randint(5,7)
                #Performs a query of the line from the .txt file
                for j in search(query, tld="ca", num=2, stop=2, pause = pause_rand, user_agent= str(headers)):
                    stack.append(j)
```

Comment: Can you specify the library you used?

Comment: @HarshanaSerasinghe it is the python google library https://pypi.org/project/google/